# Pytorch creating dataset with augmented images

Tags: image-processing, deep-learning, pytorch

Is there a way to generate a DataLoader by creating X number of augmented images?  The code I have currently only creates a single augmented image

```
class ImageDataset(data.Dataset):
    
    def __init__(self, root_dir, transform=None):
        
        self.root_dir = root_dir
        self.img_names = os.listdir()
        self.transform = transform
        
    def __getitem__(self, index):
        
        img = Image.open(os.path.join(self.root, self.img_names[index])).convert('RGB')
        if self.transform is not None:
            img = self.transform(img)
            
        return img
            
    def __len__(self):
        
        return len(self.img_names)
```

Also, I would like to add labels where augmented images from the same image have the same label

Comment: Do you want the same transform function applied to each augmented image or would you provide X different transform functions?

Comment: The transform function is a composition of Random transforms, so they by default will be random

Answer (score 0):

Here's a couple equivalent ways you could do this.

### Option 1

We can change the dataset class itself to provide the same data multiple times. This can be accomplished by reporting a longer length and selecting the image name using index (mod length).

```
class ImageDataset(data.Dataset):
    def __init__(self, root_dir, repetitions=1, transform=None):
        self.root_dir = root_dir
        self.img_names = os.listdir()
        self.transform = transform
        self.repetitions = repetitions
        
    def __getitem__(self, index):
        img = Image.open(os.path.join(self.root,
            self.img_names[index % len(self.img_names)])).convert('RGB')
        if self.transform is not None:
            img = self.transform(img)
        return img
            
    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.img_names) * self.repetitions
```

### Option 2

Alternatively we could use a [`torch.utils.data.Subset`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/data.html#torch.utils.data.Subset) and specify the same indices multiple times.

```
# using your original implementation for ImageDataset
dataset = ImageDataset(root, transforms)
dataset = torch.utils.data.Subset(dataset, list(range(len(dataset))) * repetitions)
```

---

Comment: Option 1 looks like the answer I'm looking for.  However, index%len(self.img_names) = index, so how does that change anything about the number of image augmentations I return?